# Перевод клавиатуры в режим ввода чисел

Tags: android

Есть текстовое поле. После ввода текста и определенного события, необходимо перевести клавиатуру в режим ввода чисел и при этом сохранить возможность ввода текста. Собственно интересует как это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Когда задаешь `inputType` пишешь `number`, `decimal`... Можно руками, можно мышкой готовый потащить + можно комбинировать с помощью или   `"number|none"`.

Comment: Спасибо, помогло.
editView.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);

Comment: Ан нет. Теперь после установки такого метода. Вводить текст нельзя. Так что вопрос открыт.

Comment: поясни что конкретно надо ? просто перевод клавиатуры чтоб можно было писать в что то вроде траля1й234ля так есть на клавиатур копка перключения цифра|буква|язык, небольшой уточняющий вопрос  - на чем пишешь ? насколько обосновано написание интерфейса из кода ?

Comment: Задача просто в том, что юзер вводит в поле название затем жмет кнопку кол-во,при этом в тектс вставляется разделитель. Потом юзверь будет вводить цифры и хотелось бы что бы клава уже была переключена в режим ввода текста. после ввода кол-ва юзер может ввести еще и единицы измерения, поэтому важно оставить возможность вводить буквы.

Пример строк:
Пробежка#3 км
Отжимания#10х10
Чтение#10 минут

Потом эти строки парсятся и в БД

Answer (score 1):

Скорей всего так:

```
editText.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() 
{
     @Override
     public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Log.d("KeyBoard", "Keyboard Test Key Hit");

        switch (keyCode) 
        {
              KeyEvent.KEYCODE_POUND:

              if(editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
              {                             
                   editText.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT);
                   return true;
              }
         }
     }
}
```